# Show filename in listView and imagelist. Show filename of selected item

Tags: c#, listview, listviewitem, imagelist

I have setup the imageList and the listView.  Ideally I would like the filename to show under the image.

**UPDATED**
using the item.Tag mentioned below I was able to move some things around.  I now have the file name tracking which file is selected.  Now I just have to see if I can get the file name to show up in the listview.

Here's the new code:

```
private void GetImages()
    {
        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\pics");
        this.listView1.View = View.LargeIcon;
        this.imageList1.ImageSize = new Size(67, 100);
        this.listView1.LargeImageList = this.imageList1;
        int j = 0;
        foreach (FileInfo file in dir.GetFiles())
        {
            try
            {
                imageList1.Images.Add(file.Name, Image.FromFile(file.FullName));
                ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(file.Name);
                item.Tag = file.Name;
                item.ImageIndex = j;
                this.listView1.Items.Add(item);
                j++;
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("This is not an image file");
            }
        }
    }

    private void listView1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ListViewItem item = listView1.SelectedItems[0];
        label1.Text = item.Tag.ToString();
        int itemIndex = listView1.SelectedIndices[0];
        Image img = imageList1.Images[itemIndex];
        pictureBox1.Image = img;
    }
```

Comment: Do you need the **full path**?  If so, you could store it in the Tag property when you created the ListViewItem: `item.Tag = file.FullName`.  Then you can pull it back out and display it in label1.

Comment: If you want the full Path to show why do you put only the Name in the ImageList?

Comment: I don't need the full path since I always know what dir I'm going to be working in.

Comment: but my issue is... (I think??) I figured out how to get the tag or imagekey in.  But I also don't know how to get it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I think I've simplified some of the other answers.  With this way I'm able to get the filename to show up under the image.  Also when the image is selected I'm able harness it.

I'm using the item.tag to hold the file name.

```
private void GetImages()
    {
        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\pics");
        this.listView1.View = View.LargeIcon;
        this.imageList1.ImageSize = new Size(100, 100);
        this.listView1.LargeImageList = this.imageList1;
        int j = 0;
        foreach (FileInfo file in dir.GetFiles())
        {
            try
            {
                //this.imageList1.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(file.FullName));
                imageList1.Images.Add(file.Name, Image.FromFile(file.FullName));
                ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(file.Name);
                item.Tag = file.Name;
                item.ImageIndex = j;
                this.listView1.Items.Add(item);
                j++;
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("This is not an image file");
            }
        }
    }
```

Now in either the listview1_Click or some other call to action I am able to use the follow to harness the filename tag.

```
ListViewItem item = listView1.SelectedItems[0];
txtNewWM.Text = item.Tag.ToString();
```